# Unable to import a package in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, bottle, pipenv

I am new to Python Development and I tried to create a very simple API using Bottle Web Framework. And I got the following error: "Unable to import 'bottle'pylint(import-error)".

I am using Python 3.8.6 with pipenv.

The commands I runned were the following:

```
pipenv shell

pipenv install bottle
```

The code in the main.py file is as follows:

```
from bottle import get, run

@get('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World'

run(host='localhost', port=7819)
```

To run the main.py file, use the following command:

```
python3 main.py
```

But the previous command only works if I have the work environment running (pipenv shell).

I tried to disable the Python Linting (which I didn't want to do because it helps us) and I changed the interpreter several times.

And the error I always have is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "main.py", line 1, in <module>

from bottle import get, run

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle'
```

I don't know if it has anything to do with it but I installed pipenv with HomeBrew and Pylint was installed as an VS Code extension.

Thank you guys, I am just tired of trying so many different solutions and the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the script file open cmd and change directory to your script and run
pip install bottle.
and pip install shell
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Heyo, it seems you are doing `pipenv install bottler` even though you are trying to use `bottle` in your code. Instead, try running `pipenv install bottle`, this can be a potential fix, so please let me know if this has helped!

---

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled bottle while writting the question. 

Comment: No worries! Andrej's answer may be of some help as well. It has to do with using `pip install bottle` instead of `pipenv`, (if this happens to be the fix, be sure to mark their answer as solved and not mine :p)